# Google Sheets formula to add case-insensitive text + text in cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some text on row A, and I want to write on cell E1 to filter whenever I put this formula

```
=Filter(A1:A10;ArrayFormula(E1 REGEXMATCH(A1:A10;E1)))
```

but I want it to CONTAINS not EXACT text

```
=filter(A1:A10;REGEXMATCH(A1:A10;"(i?) TEX"))
```

This works but I want to add a cell value

so somehow to combine this to together

I'm trying to put value in cell E1 `(?i)TEX` and it finds `TEXT` on A row, but I want to put `(?i)` in the formula but can't find how to do it.

I tried

```
=Filter(A1:A10;ArrayFormula(E1 REGEXMATCH(A1:A10;"(i?) +"E1"")))
```

doesn't work

```
=Filter(A1:A10;ArrayFormula(E1 REGEXMATCH(A1:A10;"(i?)"+E1)))
```

doesn't work

```
=filter(A1:A10;REGEXMATCH(A1:A10;"(i?)&" "&E1"))
```

doesn't work

I really don't have an idea of how to add `(i?)` to cell value

Comment: so atleast i managed to get working by add on E2 (?i) 
 and text on g2 cell but still cant find to add that all only in formula=Filter(A1:A10;ArrayFormula(REGEXMATCH(A1:A10;E2&" "&G2)))

Comment: Please improve formatting in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a match case-insensitive you'll need (?i) instead of (i?). I believe this should work

```
=filter(A1:A10;REGEXMATCH(A1:A10; "(?i)"&E1))
```